# union de 3 tablas en una

Tags: sql-server

Hola mundo programador.......
tengo una duda espero que me puedan ayudar lo que pasa es que tengo una tabla en sql 
con los siguiente campos :

```
LINEA  varchar(10) primary key
GRUPO varchar(10) primary key
SUB_GRUPO varchar(10) primary key
,DESCRIPCION LARGA  varchar(50)
DESCRIPCION CORTA  varchar(10)
```

lo que intento hacer a ca en esta tabla es unir 3 tablas en una me explico:
el campo linea pertenecia a una tabla llamada LINEA con su descripcion larga y corta, 
el campo grupo pertenecia a una tabla llamada GRUPO con su descripcion larga y corta, y así para el sub_grupo

Lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente:

que al momento de registrar una nueva Linea se guarde en el campo linea con su descripción larga y corta, los campos grupo y sub grupos deven estar vacios,

```
LINEAS | GRUPOS | SUB_GRUPOS | DESCRIP_LARGA   |  DESCRIP_CORTA
tableros |      |            | tableros de plasticos | tabplas
```

y al momento de registrar un GRUPO deben aparecer las LINEAS existentes para poder crear el grupo , por consecuencia el campo sub_grupo debe estar vacio,

```
LINEAS   | GRUPOS     | SUB_GRUPOS | DESCRIP_LARGA   |  DESCRIP_CORTA
tableros | empotrados |            | empotrados de 2      | emp2
```

y por ultimo que cuando quiere agregar un sub_grupo 1ero tengo que saber la linea luego el grupo y ahi crear el  nuevo sub_grupo no se si me dejo entender,

```
LINEAS   | GRUPOS    | SUB_GRUPOS   | DESCRIP_LARGA   |  DESCRIP_CORTA
tableros |empotrados  | tapa blanca | tapas de 4      | tab4
```

esa es al forma que quiero guardar mis datos en una sola tabla espero que me puedan ayudar o dar una alternativa de solucion.

Comment: Por favor fijate si podes editar la pregunta, dale formato, para que sea más fácil de leer.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola.. no entiendo para nada cual es el problema que planteas.. como ingresas los datos??? y explica mejor la dificultad que se te presenta..

Comment: Es cierto, tu pregunta no está completa, es decir, lo que has explicado es la forma como quieres llevar el registro de los datos, pero, por donde van a ingresar los mismos? desde Sql con store procedure o un script, desde php, java, etc!? Analiza y edita tu pregunta, ya que al comienzo solo con leer el titulo pense que lo que querias hacer era el uso de UNION con varias tablas. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Como primer punto debes tener claro que estás faltando a las reglas de normalización y diseño conceptual de bases de datos.
Dicho lo anterior, si deseas insertar valores nulos en las columnas Grupos y SubGrupos, debes quitar la opción de clave primaria o Primary Key de la creación de tu tabla. Como regla general una Clave no te aceptará valores nulos.

Para garantizar la integridad de tus datos, el diseño que deberías tener es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo el script con el que se crearon las tablas que muestro en la imagen:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Lineas
    (
    LineaID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Linea varchar(50) NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Lineas ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Lineas PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    LineaID
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Lineas SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Grupos
    (
    GrupoID int NOT NULL,
    LineaID varchar(50) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Grupos ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Grupos PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    GrupoID
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Grupos ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_Grupos_Lineas FOREIGN KEY
    (
    LineaID
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Lineas
    (
    LineaID
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Grupos SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.SubGrupos
    (
    SubGrupoID int NOT NULL,
    GrupoID int NOT NULL,
    SubGrupo varchar(50) NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SubGrupos ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_SubGrupos PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    SubGrupoID
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SubGrupos ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_SubGrupos_Grupos FOREIGN KEY
    (
    GrupoID
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Grupos
    (
    GrupoID
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SubGrupos SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```